# module 'cudnn' not found

Tags: lua, torch, luarocks

Trying to run https://github.com/rtqichen/style-swap

```
th style-swap.lua --content images/content/bike.jpg --style images/style/starry_night.jpg
{
  gpu : 0
  saveOriginal : false
  style : "images/style/starry_night.jpg"
  decoder : ""
  tv : 1e-07
  optim : false
  patchSize : 3
  init : "content"
  saveLoss : false
  layer : "relu3_1"
  printEvery : 50
  save : "output"
  learningRate : 0.05
  maxStyleSize : 512
  numSwap : 1
  content : "images/content/bike.jpg"
  maxContentSize : 640
  contentBatch : ""
  cpu : false
  optimIter : 100
  pooling : "max"
  patchStride : 1
}
Loading Lua modules...
/usr/bin/luajit: /usr/share/lua/5.1/trepl/init.lua:389: module 'cudnn' not found:
    no field package.preload['cudnn']
    no file './cudnn.lua'
    no file '/usr/share/luajit-2.1.0-beta3/cudnn.lua'
    no file '/usr/local/share/lua/5.1/cudnn.lua'
    no file '/usr/local/share/lua/5.1/cudnn/init.lua'
    no file '/usr/share/lua/5.1/cudnn.lua'
    no file '/usr/share/lua/5.1/cudnn/init.lua'
    no file './cudnn.so'
    no file '/usr/local/lib/lua/5.1/cudnn.so'
    no file '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/lua/5.1/cudnn.so'
    no file '/usr/local/lib/lua/5.1/loadall.so'
stack traceback:
    [C]: in function 'error'
    /usr/share/lua/5.1/trepl/init.lua:389: in function 'require'
    style-swap.lua:65: in main chunk
    [C]: in function 'dofile'
    /usr/lib/torch-trepl/th:149: in main chunk
    [C]: at 0x5587020201d0
```

How to install cudnn?

```
sudo luarocks install cudnn

Error: No results matching query were found.

sudo luarocks install cutorch

Error: No results matching query were found.

sudo luarocks install cunn

Error: No results matching query were found.
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems `torch` have it's own version of `luarocks` https://github.com/szagoruyko/loadcaffe/issues/48#issuecomment-189981690